# how to get connection string from web.config file at design time in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I can read connection string from web.config file at run time.But when i try to get connection string at design time, Null Exception throws.

How to get connection string at design time?

Comment: What do you mean "get at design time"?

Comment: I want to read connection string in my custom server control designer cs file. I can read connection string in run time.But design time not working

Comment: I think you've confused "design time" and "designer". You shouldn't modify the .designer.cs file, that's generated by Visual Studio. You should only modify the code behind `.aspx.cs` file. And code only runs at run time (hence the name).

Comment: I want create custom server control, I want to update data in .aspx file while my control rendered in .aspx. So i need connection string for update the data.